# Trouble in making hidden button Visible

Tags: iphone

Following code i am writing to hide some buttons in viewDidLoad. Here Buttons Are hiding

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 for (int i = 100; i<117; i++) 
    {
        UIButton *smileyButton = (UIButton *)[scroll viewWithTag:i];
        UITextField *smileyFields = (UITextField *)[scroll viewWithTag:i];
        UIImageView *smileyImage = (UIImageView *)[scroll viewWithTag:i];
        smileyFields.hidden = YES;
        smileyButton.hidden = YES;
    }  
}
```

Now in Following Action am making Buttons Visible. But buttons are not Visible

```
-(IBAction)editButton:(id)sender
{
 for (int i = 100; i<117; i++) 
    {
        UIButton *smileyButton = (UIButton *)[scroll viewWithTag:i];
        UITextField *smileyFields = (UITextField *)[scroll viewWithTag:i];
        UIImageView *smileyImage = (UIImageView *)[scroll viewWithTag:i];
        [smileyFields setHidden:NO];   //TextFields Not Visible 
        [smileyButton setHidden:NO];  //Buttons Not Visbile
   }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure your `editButton:` method is called?

Comment: What are their tags? Your current code assumes each tag from 100 to 116 is associated with 3 views.

Comment: @Alexander: yes its calling. all other functionality in the method are going fine.

Comment: @kevboh: 1 tag associated with textField, all other tags are for buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have several views with the same tag, function viewWithTag will return only one view, so if you call this 3 times, you get always the same view.

To do what you want, you could iterate all subviews and check tags:

```
for (UIView *aView in scrollView.subviews) {
    if (aView.tag >= 100 && aView.tag < 117) {
        aView.hidden = NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: If this is the case.. why its not happening in viewDidLoad?

Comment: @Shreedhar: interestinh, but Bartek is right about several views with the same tag. If you're using IB you might consider placing different views into different IBOutletCollections.

Answer (score 0):

Are you building the view controller in Interface Builder? If so, set the Tag of each thing you want to hide to a different number: try something simple like 1, 2, 3, etc. If you're building in code set the `tag` property instead. Remember your maximum tag number (let's assume it's 4).

Then add the following to your .h:

```
- (void)setTaggedViewsHidden:(BOOL)hidden;
```

and the following to your .m:

```
- (void)setTaggedViewsHidden:(BOOL)hidden {
  for (NSInteger tag = 1; tag <= 4; tag++) {
    [scroll viewWithTag:tag].hidden = hidden;
  }
}
```

In your `viewDidLoad` call it like so:

```
[self setTaggedViewsHidden:YES];
```

and in your `editButton:` selector call it as:

```
[self setTaggedViewsHidden:NO];
```

Remember to adjust the code in `setTaggedViewsHidden` to match the tags you're using. The best way to do this is to `#define` a constant for the min and max tags and use those in the `for` loop.

Comment: Bonus points would likely include animating the `alpha` property in the views to fade them in and out instead of suddenly showing or hiding them.